# Forcing a single column, full width table

Tags: tables, include

I am writing multiple documents like `paper.tex`, `report.tex`, `book.tex` etc. They all have different formats like single/double column, landscape/portrait etc.

All these (wrapper like) document tex files, include a single core contents file called "`content.tex`". Thus, this content gets formatted according to different formats declared by the wrapper tex files.

Question is: I wish to have a table inside `content.tex`, which gets displayed, only as single-column-full-paper-width and landscape mode, irrespective of wrapper tex's settings.

Possible?

Tried: Before this table I can say `\onecolumn`. But at the end of the table, I would not know whether to reset it to `\onecolumn` or `\twocolumn` as `content.tex` is not aware of who is including it.

Comment: Have you tried the `table*` environment? It acts like a `table` environment, but is full-width.

Comment: Is this table the same for all of them? What about the page that it's on? If *all* things remain the same, create a single, stand-alone PDF and include the table using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).

Comment: This table and the file within which it resides, content.tex is same for all the wrapper documents. Basically I wish to get the essay(content) displayed in different format, but the table has only specific format in all the docs.

Answer (score 3):

## Single/double column detection

LaTeX maintains a switch `\if@twocolumn` for the status of two column mode.
An example for the detection of the column mode with restoring the previous setting can be found in the definition for the index, e.g. `article.cls`:

```
\newenvironment{theindex}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecolfalse
  \else
    \@restonecoltrue
  \fi
  \twocolumn[\section*{\indexname}]%
  ...
}{%
  \if@restonecol
    \onecolumn
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
}
```

In a similar way, a environment can be defined to set its contents in one column mode:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{one-column}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \def\restorecolumnmode{\twocolumn\relax}%
    \onecolumn
  \else
    \def\restorecolumnmode{\clearpage}%
  \fi
}{%
  \restorecolumnmode
}
```

## Detecting `landscape` setting

If option `landscape` is set (class option, package `geometry`, ...), then the paper width is larger than paper height, which can be detected by a comparison in `\ifdim`:

```
\ifdim\paperwidth>\paperheight
  % landscape setting
\else
  % portrait setting
\fi
```